# knowing (A-B) $\cup$ B=A is not true, prove what (A-B) $\cup$ B is equal to

Tags: analysis

knowing $(A-B) \cup B=A$ is not true, prove what $(A-B) \cup B$ is equal to

I have $(A-B) \cup B = A \cup B$. my proof is let $x \in (A-B) \cup B$ where $x \in (A-B)$ or $x \in B$. If $x \in (A-B) \cup B$ then, $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$.

This is where I get stuck. I'm not even sure if I'm right or how to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in$ LHS then $x \in A-B$ or $x \in B$. In first case $x \in A$ and hence $x \in A\cup B$. In second case $x \in B$, so $x \in A\cup B$. So, in either case  $x \in A\cup B$. Conversely, if  $x \in A\cup B$ the consider two possibilities: $x \in B$, $x \notin B$. If $x \in B$ then $x \in $ LHS. Otherwise, $x \in A-B$ and $x \in $ LHS again.